# How to add Custom CSS File and why it is not rendering to page

Tags: sxa, media-library, css

I have installed Sitecore 10 on my laptop recently and I am facing the following issues.

**Issue 1:**

I have created a site and I am trying to add a "custom css file" but I am not able to upload CSS file it's showing below error.

> "An error occurred while uploading a file. The reason may be that the
> file does not exist or the path is wrong."

screenshot
[image]

**Issue 2:**

At the end Somehow I have managed to add a 'custom css file' in "media library" in "Themes" node inside "styles" folder but that "custom css file" is not rendering on the page (website).

screen shot:
[image]

Can anyone suggest me please what configuration is required to add a "custom css file" in Sitecore 10 and why it's not rendering to the page?

Regards
Firoz

Comment: Can you please share the exact css item path where you uploaded? Do you want to render the css in all the pages in the website?

Comment: Check this link out if helpful: 
https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/add-styles-and-scripts-to-sitecore-forms.html
https://therelentlessfrontend.com/2018/03/15/adding-custom-css-class-to-sitecore-rich-text-editor/

Comment: Might want to take a look at this section and in particular the Creative Exchange/ SXA themes approach https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/sxa/100/sitecore-experience-accelerator/front-end.html

Comment: item path: 
Media Library > Themes > Tenant Folder > Tenant > site node > Styles > custom-style.css
 
yes i want to render the CSS in all pages of the website.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you have `pre-optimized-min` item created under the folder to which you try to upload custom styles.

Did you re-generate `pre-optimize-min` file after adding your custom one? If SXA will find `pre-optimize-min` file it will always take it and skip generation of normal `optimize-min` file.

If you want to check if your styles will be included in the page, remove the `pre-optimize-min` file, open page in EE and check if generated `optimize-min` file contaisn your custom styles.

Comment: thanks... i deleted pre-optimize-min now it's rendering custom css file.